# Как получить данные из переменной в js файле и сохранить ее в базе данных не используя форму (Django)

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

Суть такова, что пользователь регистрируется, играет в игру, и его результат записывается в таблице (под score)

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    score                   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Везде предлагают использовать ajax запросы, но во всех примерах используют форму.

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p class="authentication-title" >Hello {{ user.username }}</p>
<p class="authentication-title" >Your best score: {{ user.score }}</p>
<a class="authentication-title" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
<h1 class="authentication-title"><a class="authentication-title" href="{% url 'register' %}">Registration</a>|<a class="authentication-title" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></h1>
{% endif %}
<h1  id="level-title">Your score now: </h1>
```

Как отправить и сохранить просто переменную (currentScore).

```
function startOver(currentScore) {
score = 0;
gamePattern = [];
started = false;
}
```

views.py

```
def game(request):
context = {}
return render(request, 'game.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Без ajax вам нужно использовать простые формы HTML и инициировать отарвку через JS

Например:

```js
function startOver(currentScore) {
  document.getElementById('scoresField').value = currentScore;
  document.getElementById('scoresFrom').submit();
  console.log(currentScore);
  score = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
  started = false;
}
```

```html
<form action="/scores-route" id="scoresFrom" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" id="scoresField" name="scores" />
</form>

<button onClick="startOver(100)">Game over</button>
```

Но лучше использовать AJAX - это удобнее, безопаснее!

Answer (score 0):

Решение на собственный вопрос:

```
    // Получаем уровень за игру
function send_score(level) {
    let best_score = Number('{{ user.score }}'); // Получим рекордное количество
    // Проверяем, больше ли наш уровень рекорда
    if (level > best_score) {
        username = "{{ user.username }}"; // Определяем username пользователя
        // Заносим все в словарь, чтобы потом прочитать это в views.py
        send_data = {
            'username':username,
            "score":level,
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken":"{{ csrf_token }}", // Для пост запроса нужен csrf токен
        };
        // Отправляем ajax запрос
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "{% url 'game' %}",
                type:"post",
                data:send_data, // Отправляем словарь
                // Если данные отправлены, выводим новый best_score
                success:function (data) {
                    best_score = send_data['score'];
                    $('#best_score').text('Your best score: ' + best_score);
                },
                // Если какая-то ошибка, выводим в консоль
                error:function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
            }
        }
    )
   }
 }
```

views.py

```
   def game(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST: # Проверяем, был ли отправлен POST запрос
        username = request.POST.get('username') # Получим username из словаря send_data
        score = request.POST.get('score')# Получим score из словаря send_data
        # Находим пользователя с таким username-мом и обновляем ему его score
        Account.objects.filter(username=username).update(score=score)
    return render(request, 'game.html', context)
```

Все это сделано без формы.